# Heap running out of memory on android during View inflating in a loop

Tags: android, android-layout

This maybe a newbie question. I want to add a few rows say a 200 or so to a Layout which in turn is added to a scroll view. Problem is that that somewhere in the loop it runs out of memory. So how does one go about doing this, is there a simple inflating on demand solution? any other? Thanks.

btw there is not much happening in the layouts just a few text boxes.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_stats_summary, null);    
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

View ri;
for(int i=0;i<row_info_array.size();i++){
   ri = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_details, null);

   ll.addView(ri);
}
```

Comment: Instead use ListView.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `ListView`, the way it works that only visible items are created and it can recycle views with the adapter.

Here is a simple example to get you started: http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

Answer (score 0):

Try inflating with `View.inflate` method.

`ri = View.inflate(R.layout.row_details, null);`